# attributes of subclassed classes in registry of subclassed classes

Tags: python, metaprogramming

Just following something from an example I found to integrate with part of a project where I am creating a large number of classes subclassed off of 'Something' below, and I'm trying to make steps toward a more automatic creation of these items without having to write them all out every time(because the number of items is getting large and I can reduce a lot of boilerplate by passing in a smaller list of attributes, thats the gist at least).

Anyway, given:

```
class SomethingMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'registry'):
            cls.registry = {}
        else:
            interface_id = name.lower()
            cls.registry[interface_id] = cls

        super(SomethingMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class Something(object):
    __metaclass__ = SomethingMeta

class SomethingA(Something):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

 class SomethingB(Something):
    def __init__(self, z=0):
        self.z = z
```

So I have a registry in Something.registry of classes created using 'Something'...but what I really want to do is get a list of the attributes of a 'Something' subclassed class in 'SomethingMeta'. So in the Something.registry is need to capture the attributes of a registered subclass, specific ones even, i.e. I need to know that when SomethingB is registered, that there is a SomethingB.z on it, so I can get a fingerprint of a subclassed class to key in the dictionary. Only I cannot seem to poke at what I need properly right now.

Any input appreciated, clarifications can be provided, maybe tell what exactly I'm trying to do if I'm doing it wrong, etc.

EDIT:

Wished for result. Overall I'd like to:

1) pass in a dict of the variables I need the subclassed instance to have e.g. {'x': 1, 'y': 2}

2) take the keys from this dict, and create a unique identifier/hash e.g. 34523sdfgsdg3423234234

3) get that subclass from Something.registry if that identifier exists, and instantiate an instance from that OR create a new subclass, store it in the registry  and return an instance of it e.g. Something.registry would look like {'34523sdfgsdg3423234234': }

The primary distinguishing feature of the many subclassed items is the information they carry and they all do different things with the info they carry in different ways based on other information they carry, but all common to a method in the class they are subclassed from, so I'm really just trying to create a key based on an information payload so I can start to work on more auto generation that removes redundant code, and I guess I'll figure something out.

Comment: The registry is in `Something.__dict__`, not `SomethingMeta.__dict__`. It can be put in `SomethingMeta` if you wish, but that is not where it is at the moment, given the current code.

Comment: Can you give an example of what you want the registry to look like (including the list of attributes)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `SomethingMeta.__init__` is run at the time the class `Something` (or any of its subclasses) is defined.

The attributes of an instance of `Something` are only defined when the instance is instantiated, which could happen much later, or even never.

So the registry can not inspect the instances to find out what attributes it might have.

But if you can guarantee that the attributes are all listed in the call signature of `cls.__init__`, then you could use `inspect.getargspec` to find the attribute names:

```
import inspect
class SomethingMeta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        if not hasattr(cls, 'registry'):
            cls.registry = {}
        else:
            interface_id = name.lower()
            attrs, varargs, varkw, defaults = inspect.getargspec(cls.__init__)
            cls.registry[interface_id] = [a for a in attrs 
                                          if a not in ('self', None)]

        super(SomethingMeta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)

class Something(object):
    __metaclass__ = SomethingMeta

class SomethingA(Something):
    def __init__(self, x, y, *args, **kw):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class SomethingB(Something):
    def __init__(self, z=0):
        self.z = z

print(Something.registry)
```

yields

```
{'somethingb': ['z'], 'somethinga': ['x', 'y']}
```

Comment: inspect.getargspec is something I didn't know about and gets me a bit further as an answer to my initial question.